# How to convert cv::Mat to AVFrame in ffmpeg

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

- I have one cv::Mat image.Now i want to convert this mat to AVFrame in ffmpeg.
- I have trie below code,

  ```
  void matToAVFrame(cv::Mat frame)
  {
      AVFrame *dst, *yuv422_final_frame;
        cv::Size frameSize = frame.size();
        AVCodec *encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
        AVFormatContext* outContainer = avformat_alloc_context();
        AVStream *outStream = avformat_new_stream(outContainer, encoder);
        avcodec_get_context_defaults3(outStream->codec, encoder);
        dst = av_frame_alloc();
        outStream->codec->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
        outStream->codec->width = frame.cols;
        outStream->codec->height = frame.rows;
        avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)dst, frame.data, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, outStream->codec->width, outStream->codec->height);
        dst->width = frameSize.width;
        dst->height = frameSize.height;

  //      av_image_alloc((uint8_t**)frame.data, dst->linesize,dst->width, dst->height,
  //            AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, 32);

        yuv422_final_frame = av_frame_alloc();
        int yuv422_num_bytes = avpicture_get_size( AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,  dst->width, dst->height );
        uint8_t* final_frame2_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(yuv422_num_bytes*sizeof(uint8_t));


        yuv422_final_frame->width = frameSize.width;
        yuv422_final_frame->height = frameSize.height;
        avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)yuv422_final_frame, (uchar*)dst->data, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,  dst->width, dst->height);

       SwsContext *final_sws_ctx = sws_getContext(dst->width , dst->height,
           AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, dst->width, dst->height,
           AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, 0, 0, 0);

  //     avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)dst, frame.data, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, dst->width, dst->height);
       sws_scale(final_sws_ctx, dst->data,
               dst->linesize,
                 0, dst->height,
                 yuv422_final_frame->data,
                 yuv422_final_frame->linesize);

       Mat cvmImage = cv::Mat( yuv422_final_frame->height, yuv422_final_frame->width, CV_8UC3, yuv422_final_frame->data[2],
               yuv422_final_frame->linesize[2]);

       imwrite("/home/radix/Desktop/OpenCV/cvmImage.png", cvmImage);
  }
  int main()
  {
      av_register_all();
      Mat frame = imread("path to image");
      matToAVFrame(frame);
  }
  ```

but it is giving me some bad image, and in some cases it is not giving any image.
* So please anybody tell me where i am doing wrong.Thanks!!

- **EDIT:**
- Sometimes it gives me error like `[swscaler @ 0x1c9a6e0] bad src image pointers`
- So i am getting this type of output from above code.
- **Input Image:**

[image: InputImage]

- **output image:**

[image: outputImage]

Comment: You could include a case of _bad image_ the error is more "visual"

Comment: your openCV image must be BGR image, is it possible that you provide a yuv image instead?

Comment: No.I am providing BGR image only

Comment: but yuv422_final_frame is `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P`? And in SwsContext  you set SOURCE format to `AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24` and destination format to `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P` according to https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/group__lsws.html#gaf360d1a9e0e60f906f74d7d44f9abfdd

Comment: in addition, your code reads a cv::Mat and the function name implies that you want to convert it to AVFrame? But your question asks on how to convert AVFrame to cv::Mat?!? Which one is correct? Your code looks like it converts FROM Mat TO AVFrame, but then the last 2 code lines don't make any sense: `Mat cvmImage = cv::Mat( yuv422_final_frame->height, ...` and `imwrite("/home/radix/Desktop/OpenCV/cvmImage.png", cvmImage);` because you converted the input cv::Mat to a AVFrame and not vice versa.

Comment: @Micka: yes it's my mistake.i want to convert cv::Mat to AVFrame.

Comment: I have created cvImage for just cross checking

Comment: And using this frame i want to create video.

Comment: the cross checking is garbage. opencv expects bgr images for displaying/saving but if your code works the image you use in cross checking is yuv. So it's no surprise that the result looks strange. In fact, the triple-image is a hint that the image really is yuv. Not sure whether there is a "save AVFrame to file" function in ffmpeg. If yes you should use that.

Comment: maybe you xan try the cross checking with adding cvCvtColor(scr, dst, CV_YUV2BGR) before saving the image. If that works everything is fine but if that doesnt work it might be just not the right conversion.because there are many special codes like CV_YUV2BGR_NV12, CV_YUV2RGB_IYUV, etc. I dont know which one you would need here...